# How can I create GIF tunnel in ubuntu

Tags: vpn, tunnel

I am able to [create GRE tunnel](http://ask.xmodulo.com/create-gre-tunnel-linux.html) in ubuntu. But I know that GRE cannot carry layer2 traffic, that's why I want to use GIF tunnels instead. How can I create GIF tunnel in ubuntu ?